# Best temperature to store carboy after fermentation is complete?

Tags: temperature, storage, carboy

I've got a porter and a stout, both sitting in carboys and both have reached their desired FG reading.  However, I'm not able to keg them for another 2-3 weeks because I'm still waiting on a CO2 system, so I'd like to just leave them in the carboys until then.

Question: Am I better off leaving them at their normal fermentation temperature range (between 65F-70F), or should I move them into our basement which is currently quite cold (45F-50F)?

Comment: How long it took to stabilize the FG ? Remember that doesn't exist "desired FG" when the yeasts are alive, you cannot stop the fermentation if there is some sugar yet, more alcohol and more CO2 will be produced sometime when the temperature is nice. So keep it in fermentation temperature for some days after FG doesn't change anymore (prefer to increase it 2 to 3C, about 5F), this ensures that yeasts to consume byproducts like diacetyl and others.

Answer (score 6):

Warmer temperatures will allow the yeast to continue its work, cleaning up the beer. Colder temperatures will promote yeast flocculation which helps to clear the beer. It'd suggest leaving the beer in the fermentation temperature range for a week or two after the final gravity has been reached, and then moving it to the cooler basement to help it clear.